# align content-div element inside of wrapper-div

Tags: html, css

I have struggled to align content-div elements of a wrapper-div using only CSS with the following restriction.

1. The wrapper div can have a row which allows multiple content-div elements be on the row
2. At most 4 content-div elements can exist on a row of the wrapper div.
3. Content-div elements of the last row must expand to fill the row. (e.g if 3 content-div elements exist on the last row, then the width of each content-div should be 33.3%)
4. One and only one content-element always is selected, and the selected element should be bottom-left conner of the wrapper-div element.

To handle this, I have tried the following css.

```
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
}
.content{
   max-width:100%;
   min-width:25%;
   background-color:white;
   float:right;
}
.content.selected{
   position:absolute;
   top:100%;
   left:0;
   float:left;
   background-color:yellow;
}
```

I thought that the "float:right; float:left position:absolute; top:100%; left:0;" option can handle the restriction 1 and restriction 4, the "min-width:25%" option can handle the restriction 2 and the "max-width:100%" option can handle the restriction 3. However, only a few restriction were satisfied through the CSS.

I have setup jsFiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/6qyc5kLw/2/

I would help in this regard.

[This image is what I want to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc52w.png)

Comment: Thanks all! I have solved the problem completely. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ever considered display:flex? its HUGE!

```
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.content{

   min-width:25%;
   background-color:white;
   //float:right;
   flex:1;

   order:1;
}
.content.selected{
   //position:absolute;
   //top:100%;
   //left:0;
   //float:left;
   background-color:yellow;
   order:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The new [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) possibilities are most certainly what you are looking for. See below snippet or https://jsfiddle.net/6qyc5kLw/3/ for an updated demo with some basic flexbox properties. An additional one would be

```
flex-order (to reverse the order of elements in first row)
```

```css
    .wrapper{
      width:100%;
      position:relative;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .content{
       flex-basis: 25%;
       background-color:white;
       border: 1px solid #ccc;
       flex-grow: 1;
       box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .content.selected{
       align-self: flex-end;
       background-color:yellow;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        4
    </div>
    <div class="content selected">
        5
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        6
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        7
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display: flex

```css
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.content{
  background:#fff;
  box-flex: 1;
  min-width:25%;
  flex: 1;
  margin: auto;
}
.content.selected{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">1</div>
  <div class="content">2</div>
  <div class="content">3</div>
  <div class="content">4</div>
  <div class="content selected">5</div>
  <div class="content">6</div>
  <div class="content">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is exactly what you want in example picture:

[image]

```css
    .wrapper{
      width:100%;
      position:relative;
    }
    .content{
       max-width:100%;
       min-width:25%;
       background-color:white;
       float:right;
       border: 1px solid black;
       box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .content.selected{
       background-color:yellow;
       float: left;
       width: 33.33%;
    }

.content:nth-child(6) {
    float: right;
    width: 33.33%;
}

.content:nth-child(7) {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        4
    </div>
    <div class="content selected">
        5
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        6
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        7
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```